# JNI, C++ push string in stack

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

My C++ code, push a string to mystack

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include "NativeLogger.h"


std::stack<std::string> mystack;


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_NativeLogger_push(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,jstring name)
{

  std::string s = env->GetStringUTFChars(name, 0);

  mystack.push(s);

  return;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_NativeLogger_pop(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{

  mystack.pop();
  return;
}
```

I got follow crash report when runs with Java, any idea how to fix it?

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f29421a0207, pid=18007,
>   tid=0x00007f2942d3e700
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build
>   1.8.0_144-b01) Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops) Problematic frame: C 
>   [libc.so.6+0x97207]  __libc_malloc+0x197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java code:

```
package recipeNo025;

public class HelloWorld {

  public static native void pushString(String s);
  public static native String popString();

  static {
    System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HelloWorld.pushString("Hello");
    System.out.println(HelloWorld.popString());
  }
}
```

C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include "jni.h"
#include "recipeNo025_HelloWorld.h"

std::stack<std::string> mystack;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo025_HelloWorld_pushString
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring str) {

    // we have to get string bytes into C string
    const char *c_str;
    c_str = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, NULL);
    if(c_str == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "Passed string: " << c_str << std::endl;

    std::string my_string(c_str);
    mystack.push(my_string);

    // after using it, remember to release the memory
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, c_str);
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_recipeNo025_HelloWorld_popString
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj) {

    std::string s = mystack.top();
    mystack.pop();
    return env->NewStringUTF(s.c_str());
}
```

Execution:

```
> java -Djava.library.path=:./lib -cp target recipeNo025.HelloWorld
Passed string: Hello
Hello
```

Also, I'd have considered using Singleton pattern instead of having global variable for stack.

Comment: Hi mko, thanks for your answer.  Your code works for a simple example. I instrumented entire JDK and log methods that been push and pop from the stack. I still got the error.

Comment: Sometimes, debugging JNI might be painful. Take a look here for tips on debugging the code: https://youtu.be/8Cjeq4l5COU

Comment: Thanks again, I found out it was concurrency issue, use mutex.lock()/unlock() solved the issue.

Comment: .oOo. Cool! Have fun with JNI ;) .oOo.

Answer (score 1):

It's faily likely that `GetStringUTFChars` returned a pointer to *a copy* of the actual string, which you promptly discarded by passing it directly as an argument to `std::string`'s constructor, thereby causing a memory leak.

You need to hang on to the pointer in order to be able to free it:

```
const char *p = env->GetStringUTFChars(name, NULL);
std::string s(p);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(name, p);
```

Note that even in the unlikely case where no copy was made, you still need to call `ReleaseStringUTFChars`, because the VM might've pinned the Java string in memory which could interfere with the garbage collector.